# Space between buttons using flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here is my html

```
<div class="bets">
    <button class="name-price">
        <div class="real-madrid"><!---->Real Madrid<!----></div>
        <div class="price"><!---->1.23<!----></div>
    </button>

    <button class="name-price">
        <div class="barcelona"><!---->Barcelona<!----></div>
        <div class="price"><!---->2.05<!----></div>
    </button>
</div>
```

Here is SASS

```
.bets
    display: flex
    justify-content: space-between
```

Space between buttons using flex is not working as expected.
What am I missing?
[image]

Mark-up change based on suggestion in comments. Still same result:
[image]

CSS rules are applied to elements when I inspect it:
[image]

Comment: the semi colon after `display: flex`

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed it's not a CSS code, no need semi colon

Comment: sorry, thats mb

Comment: What browser are you using? And do you have parents of bets?

Comment: Your code is working as expected. Please inspect your elements through console to make sure the CSS rules are indeed applied to the elements. Btw, just to make sure, have you transpiled your SASS into CSS?

Comment: I see it worked. Link here: https://jsfiddle.net/bL95tejk/1/. So please check what your browser are you using and check the CSS in browser make sure it transpired right with your want.

Comment: This codepen is a great example: https://codepen.io/greengiraffe/pen/EyzkZY

Comment: Do you need as displayed on the image?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BWya.png

Comment: @SJSJSJSJ, I checked in Chrome, Safari and Firefox. Parent of bets is a flex item.

Comment: @YongQuan, I see css rules applying when I inspect the element. Attached screenshot in description.

Comment: @Yudiz_Webdesign, I do not need to as displayed on the image.

Comment: After applying 100% width, it is displayed as expected now. Thank you all for your help.